# Get an specific node with HtmlAgilityPack and web request

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, html-agility-pack

im trying to get an specific field from web page and this is my code:

```
Dim htmlDocument As New HtmlDocument
Const node As String = "//*[@id='table_menu_right']/tbody/tr[1]/td/table[3]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/p[1]"
Dim webReq As System.Net.WebRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://dof.gob.mx")
Dim webRes As System.Net.WebResponse = webReq.GetResponse()
Dim mystream As System.IO.Stream = webRes.GetResponseStream()
If mystream IsNot Nothing Then
Dim myHtmlDoc As New HtmlDocument()
myHtmlDoc.Load(mystream)
Dim nodo As HtmlNode = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(node)
```

But i get Null at the next Line:

```
Dim tipoCambio As String = nodo.InnerText
txtTipoDeCambio.Text = tipoCambio
End If
```

I've tried with local html file and i get it the way i want but when i use WebRequest i get Null.

Does anybody know how could i do this correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Save the data you get with `WebRequest` and compare the files.

Answer (score 0):

remove paragraph tag and then check it. also check is there any form tag if yes then remove